# Mirror negative space to positive

Tags: modeling, transforms, mirror

[image: strong text]
Is there any way to  mirror/symmetrize curve in object A  along X axis to get the result with B.

Comment: Do you mean procedurally? There must be a reason that extruding to the right and deleting on the left isn't good enough?

Comment: yeah i can do it manually no problem , was just wondering if there is any way to do it using mirror. plus sometimes the geometry you want to project is not a simple as in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's hard to imagine an applicable usecase, you could do this:
[image: image example]

The Hook modifier is linked to an empty that's been scaled by -1 along the x axis, to invert the first inversion by the mirror modifier.

You must also make vertex groups, with a `.R` and `.L` in the names, and set one of them to all the vertices of the shape you want flipped. Select the other Vertex group in the Hook modifier